# How to hide Action menu from all document libraries after migrating to Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am migrating MOSS 2007 site to Sahrepoint 2010 without UI upgrade. In all document libraries I am able to view Action menu. How do I remove it from all document libraries. Also In one document library users have read access and when they open in explorer view, they are able to delete document. How do I solve this

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below javascript in allitems.aspx to hide the action menu:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Documents/jquery.hiding-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var link = $('a[id$="ListActionsMenu"]').filter(':contains("Actions")');
    link.parent().hide();
});
</script>
```